# How to read the old json string, if you decide to rename fields in class (Using gson)

Tags: java, json, gson

Previously, we have the following class

```
public class Checklist {
    private final long id;
    private String text;
    private boolean checked;

    public Checklist(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

---

The following json operation (String to object) works pretty well.

```
String string = "[{\"checked\":false,\"id\":0,\"text\":\"Boodschappen\"},{\"checked\":false,\"id\":1,\"text\":\"Melk\"}]";

GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
final Gson gson = builder.create();
List<Checklist> checklists = gson.fromJson(string, new TypeToken<List<Checklist>>() {}.getType());

for (Checklist checklist : checklists) {
    System.out.println("--> " + checklist.getText());
}
```

---

Now, we "upgrade" the class to the following, in order to preserve disk space.

```
public class Checklist {

    @SerializedName("i")
    private final long id;
    @SerializedName("t")
    private String text;
    @SerializedName("c")
    private boolean checked;

    public Checklist(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

---

It will work with new json String

```
String string = "[{\"c\":false,\"i\":0,\"t\":\"Boodschappen\"},{\"c\":false,\"i\":1,\"t\":\"Melk\"}]";

GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
final Gson gson = builder.create();
List<Checklist> checklists = gson.fromJson(string, new TypeToken<List<Checklist>>() {}.getType());

for (Checklist checklist : checklists) {
    System.out.println("--> " + checklist.getText());
}
```

But, we still would like to able, to convert the old json string back to new Object.

```
String oldString = "[{\"checked\":false,\"id\":0,\"text\":\"Boodschappen\"},{\"checked\":false,\"id\":1,\"text\":\"Melk\"}]";
```

May I know how I can achieve so?

Comment: Have you tried using the alternate element on the SerializedName to provide an alternative name for the json field?

Comment: Sorry. I do not understand "alternate element on the SerializedName". Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass **alternate** as an argument to SerializedName

`@SerializedName(value = "fullName", alternate = "username")`

Please [refer](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) to this Javadoc